# Coldfusion deployment process

Tags: deployment, coldfusion, tomcat7, coldfusion-10

I am trying to figure out what's the best process to implement for build & deployment for coldfusion project.

I am much more familiar with the regular java stack: some back-end framework (Spring, Struts, etc), bunch of JSP files, then use maven to compile and bundle everything to a .war file that I simply deploy (copy) over to a tomcat webapp directory

Are cfm files practically same as jsp? What are the similarities & differences between Java vs Coldfusion build/deploy process?

The resources I found so far make it sound like to just copy & paste the physical files, which doesn't sound quite right.

The thread here [Best Practices for Code/Web Application Deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005298/best-practices-for-code-web-application-deployment) - goes on the generic deployment process, which we already have implemented. We have code repository and maven to manage our build & deployment process, can coldfusion work straight out of the box with the same set up as regular Java/war projects?

A thread in Adobe forum does not give much insights either: [Deploying ColdFusion 8 project via EAR/WAR file](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2516340), plus it talks about EAR rather than WAR.

This is an old link from 2007: [build tools: maven and coldfusion](http://jochem.vandieten.net/2010/01/15/using-ear-files-for-coldfusion-deployments/)  seem to indicate maven is not straight out of the box solution, also seems like Coldfusion has no need for dependency management that maven is so useful for?

Can someone help point me to the right direction for build & deployment of coldfusion projects with the following stack:

- Code repository, doesn't matter much: Git, svn
- Maven build
- Deploy project as war into Tomcat7 (not built in)
- MySQL db connector

and Lastly - how would the solution be different between CF8 vs CF10? Looks to me CF8 may be worse as it doesn't officially support Tomcat, whereas CF10 runs on modified version of Tomcat?

Thanks!

Comment: In our case, it's what the web server administrators permit.  You should talk to yours.

Comment: Practically can do anything to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to deploying CFML out the box then you really just have to copy and paste the file into your web server. In your case if you are using git just pull it from your repository. You don't have to do anything other then that. However, in some cases you may need to clear your CFML Cache if you don't see the changes immediately. This is my personal process:

1. Make changes on local machine running a CFML Development environment.
2. Commit and Push changes to git repository.
3. Pull changes to Production Server
4. Clear cache if needed.

It really is simple as that as long as your code makes it that simple.

Comment: That's because CFML is practically equivalent of JSPs? Does coldfusion not have Java-style classes that actually needs to be compiled and loaded (and thus can't simply be copied over)

Comment: @TS-, Technically, CF is a JSP, but you are writing it in a higher level language. CF code is automatically compiled the first time it is executed. You can manually compile it with `cfcompile` command line, if you desire, but is unnecessary. Doing so really just helps speed up the initial request in which compiling would normally occur.

Comment: Ah thank you, so all I need is have that initial CF install to the stand-alone tomcat, from there on I just need to copy-paste any changes that I make?

Comment: @TS-, yes. Copy/paste is one specific way to transfer files. You could use any file transfer method you like: FTP, Robocopy, Ant, SVN update, Git pull, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

I have worked on some substantial apps were the process was zip up all the files, send them to a deployment team and they will unzip at the appropriate location.

Answer 2:

I suspect you are looking for something like CAR files. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd3.html